# JMeter Plugins when Executing from Maven

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

Is it possible to use [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) when executing JMeter from the [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/Ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin/)?

**UPDATE**

I've tried adding the `jmeter-plugins` dependency to the plugin definition as per Ardesco's helpful answer, but I get a myriad of `ClassNotFoundException`s. It *seems* like Maven is not putting `jmeter-plugin`'s transitive dependencies on the classpath when executing JMeter. Any ideas?

Comment: See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47602584/460802

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Although this answer is accepted, it only works for versions before 2.X.
But for version higher than 2.X, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47602584/460802).**

Yup, you can add any libraries you require by adding dependencies to the plugin, any explicitly defined dependencies will be copied to your jmeter/lib directory.

If the dependency is a JMeter plugin you can specify this in your configuration and then that dependency will be copied to your meter/lib/ext directory:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jmeter</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <jmeterPlugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </jmeterPlugins>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

This functionality was broken before version 1.9.0.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me - I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException` whenever it tries to run a test.

Comment: You'll need to raise a bug to get that investigated.  It's probably because the plugin isn't loading transitive dependancies right now (Needs investigation).  The work around would be to specify the transitive dependancies explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think the issue is slightly different, and whilst you were replying I raised a plugin bug: https://github.com/Ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/77

Comment: Does that load all the plugins, including 'jmeter-plugins-webdriver' plugin or just a certain smaller set?

Comment: It should pull in whatever is in the jmeter-plugins jar.

Answer (score 4):

Use version 2.6.0 or upper of the [plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

and add:

```
<configuration>
    <jmeterExtensions>
         <artifacts>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.4</artifacts>
    </jmeterExtensions>
    <excludedArtifacts>
        <exclusion>commons-pool2:commons-pool2</exclusion>
        <exclusion>commons-math3:commons-math3</exclusion>
    </excludedArtifacts>
    ...
</configuration>
```

See this tutorial for a complete overview of using the maven plugin :

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/shift-left-performance-tests-jmeter-maven/

Answer (score 0):

**jmeter 3.4.0**

If you have any external dependencies please use the below one.

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                
                <!--testPlanLibraries - if you have any dependency with external jars pls add artifact here-->
                <!-- beanshell preprocessor you can write java so this is useful-->
                <testPlanLibraries>
                     <artifact>com.konghq:unirest-java:3.11.11</artifact>
                 </testPlanLibraries>

                <testFilesDirectory>src/test/jmeter</testFilesDirectory>
                <suppressJMeterOutput>false</suppressJMeterOutput>
                <appendResultsTimestamp>true</appendResultsTimestamp>
                <downloadJMeterDependencies>true</downloadJMeterDependencies>
                <downloadLibraryDependencies>true</downloadLibraryDependencies>
                <downloadExtensionDependencies>true</downloadExtensionDependencies>
                <downloadOptionalDependencies>true</downloadOptionalDependencies>
                <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                    <!-- for setting any arguments please use this section -->
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-Dhttps.use.cached.ssl.context=false</argument>
                        <argument>-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks</argument>
                        <argument>-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${clientCertKeystorePath}</argument>
                        <argument>-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=${keyStorePassword}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>configuration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>configure</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>results</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

You can check the **${project-root}/target/long-folder-name/jmeter/lib/** and make sure your jar is present there. For me i have a dependency with **Urirest** for making a post to get the token.