# JMeter Plugins via jmeter-maven-plugin failed to execute

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use JMeter Plugins with jmeter-maven-plugin as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398268/1639134
but it failed:

```
Cause: Error loading class 'com.lazerycode.jmeter.Plugin'
```

the whole stacktrace:

```
user@dom0:~/tmp/m$ time mvn -e verify | tee mvn.out
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - org.company.app:jmeter-tests:jar:0.0.1
[INFO]    task-segment: [verify]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/user/tmp/m/src/main/resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/user/tmp/m/src/test/resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/user/tmp/m/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}]
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /home/user/tmp/m/target/jmeter-tests-0.0.1.jar
[WARNING] POM for 'kg.apc:perfmon:pom:1.0.0:compile' is invalid.

Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to configure plugin parameters for: com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.9.0



Cause: Error loading class 'com.lazerycode.jmeter.Plugin'
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error configuring: com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin. Reason: Unable to parse the created DOM for plugin configuration
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:723)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginConfigurationException: Error configuring: com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin. Reason: Unable to parse the created DOM for plugin configuration
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultPluginManager.java:1363)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:724)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:468)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurationException: Error loading class 'com.lazerycode.jmeter.Plugin'
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.CollectionConverter.fromConfiguration(CollectionConverter.java:170)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.ComponentValueSetter.configure(ComponentValueSetter.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:137)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.BasicComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(BasicComponentConfigurator.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultPluginManager.java:1357)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lazerycode.jmeter.Plugin
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.CollectionConverter.fromConfiguration(CollectionConverter.java:158)
        ... 24 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jan 26 16:04:46 MSK 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 52M/612M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

real    0m7.343s
user    0m14.033s
sys     0m0.465s
```

this is my simplest pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.company.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-tests</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jmeter</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <jmeterPlugins>
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                </jmeterPlugins>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: what is in your src/test/jmeter directory?  Does it work if you don't add a dependency to jmeter-plugins?

Comment: The problem was fixed after installing maven 3 (3.0.4 from standard ubuntu repositories). The problem was on maven 2.2

Comment: Interesting, can you raise a bug at https://github.com/Ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues and put in the POM that was causing you problems.  It should work in both maven 2 and maven 3

Comment: posted https://github.com/Ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/92

Answer (score 2):

Adding an answer here so that people don't have to go to the links in the comments above.

The issue is that jmeter-plugins 1.0.0 is missing a reference to some perfmon libraries. It's working in mvn 3 because mvn 3 is more forgiving of transitive dependency errors.

I've tried excluding perfmon from the dependency in mvn2, but it still will not work. The jmeter-plugins team to release an updated version of the plugin without transitive dependency errors.

The workaround is to use maven 3.