# Error loading class 'com.lazerycode.jmeter.Plugin'

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

jmeter-maven-plugin declaration in my maven file looks as follows

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
   <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.10.1</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>jmeter-tests</id>
         <phase>verify</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>jmeter</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <jmeterPlugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
                </plugin>
             </jmeterPlugins>
          </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
          <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.1</version>
          <type>pom</type>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

However on mvn clean install with maven 2, I get the following error

Error loading class 'com.lazerycode.jmeter.Plugin'

I have found a related issues here

[JMeter Plugins via jmeter-maven-plugin failed to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363298/jmeter-plugins-via-jmeter-maven-plugin-failed-to-execute)

and here

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/92

But both links are using jmeter-plugins version 1.0.0. I am using jmeter-plugins version 1.3.1. Is this issue still around with mvn2 and jmeter-plugins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are still problems with jmeter-plugins 1.3.1, but this time it's not really thier fault. They depend upon JMeter 2.12 which was always broken. See these bugs:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57649
- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57555

jmeter-plugins needs to depend upon a different version of JMeter, one that has all of its transitive dependencies.  This information is also available here:

- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/142

Comment: I just checked the pom files of jmeter-plugins 1.3.1 for all their projects over here https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/

It seems like jmeter-plugins 1.3.1 depend on jmeter 2.13. Is that version of jmeter buggy too. Also the class it is failing to load on my side when i do mvn clean install is "com.lazerycode.jmeter.Plugin" which has package name corresponding to group id of jmeter-maven-plugin. Why do you think the fault is in the jmeter-plugins?

Comment: Also I dont see the Plugin.java in here

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/jmeter. Is there class coming from some dependency of jmeter-maven-plugin

Comment: Also if I take this portion out  <jmeterPlugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
                </plugin>
             </jmeterPlugins>

then mvn clean install runs fine for me.

Comment: Yes 2.13 has transient dependency issues as well: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57734.  Hopefully 2.14 will be a better release...  I think it's an issue with meter-plugins 1.3.1 because it all works fine if you remove the plugin configuration.  If you can provide a log showing the error and the stack trace I'll be able to be more helpful.